# Add a value to a specific position in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't know how to add my value to my Array, my array always return me null. I create my array in another function call before this one.

```
function doClick() {
$[this.id].addEventListener('change', function(e) {
if(e.value !=0)
{
Ti.API.info(this.id);


var myValue = e.value;
Ti.API.info(myValue);

var str = this.id;
var char1 = str.substr(9,1);
var char2 = str.substr(11,1);

var nb1 = parseInt(char1);
var nb2 = parseInt(char2);

Ti.API.info(nb1);
Ti.API.info(nb2);

matrix[nb1][nb2] = myValue;

Ti.API.info(matrix[nb1][nb2]);
}

});     
}
```

My logs are the following

[INFO] :   TextField1x4

[INFO] :   8

[INFO] :   1

[INFO] :   4

[INFO] :   null

Comment: When on what element or so does the `doClick()` function get triggered? Does `$` refer ro `jquery`?

Comment: My doClick is triggered here:
<TextField class="little_square" id="TextField0x0" onClick="doClick"></TextField>

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a multidimensional array before you can use it.

```
matrix = [];
matrix[nb1] = [];
matrix[nb1][nb2] = myValue;
```

Reference: http://www.stephanimoroni.com/how-to-create-a-2d-array-in-javascript/

Comment: I think it's already done here:

`function init() {
 for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
  for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++)
   matrix[i * 9 + j] = (i * 3 + Math.floor(i / 3) + j) % 9 + 1;

 mask = mask(matrix);

 Ti.API.info("Matrice after mask " + mask[0] + mask[1] + mask[2]);

 var cpt = 0;
 for ( i = 0; i < 9; i++)
  for ( j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
   if (mask[cpt] !== 0) {
    $['TextField' + i + 'x' + j].value = mask[cpt];
    $['TextField' + i + 'x' + j].editable = false;
  cpt++;
  }
}`